# How to integrate AEM (6.3) with Magento (2.1.10)?

Tags: aem, magento2

I wanted to integrate AEM (6.3) with Magento (2.1.10) to show products on AEM page, I have searched a lot but not getting any proper documentation.
Although I followed below link :

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/magento.html

Through this link I got connector, and I installed that connector for AEM, But I am not able to install the connector on Magento as I am new to Magento. I'd like to add connector in Magento or integrate AEM with Magento.

Comment: Why are you "not able"? Can you clarify what exactly is not working yet?

Comment: I got a zip file form the above link and when i extracted the file, I got 2 connector, one for AEM(named : aem-connector) and other for Magento(named : magento2). And when I log in to magento with admin cred and on the dashboard, I clicked on system and then under extnsion i selected integration, but there m not getting any option to add these files

Answer (score 1):

To install the AEM extension in Magento you have to place the content of the extension under */app/code/{name of provider}/{name of extension}* (in this case, the name of the provider is *InfieldDigital* and the name of the extension is *Sample*) in your Magento instance folder.

After that, you'll be able to find your extension listed in the in the Module Manager tab under the Web Setup Wizard.

Finally, you'll have to enable said extension in Magento. After following the steps, you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with changing `jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"` to `jcr:primaryType="sling:Orderedfolder"`

Fixes:

- Replace `jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"` with `jcr:primaryType="sling:Orderedfolder"` under jcr:root(line 3) for both the below files:

  - .content.xml file under `/magento2-aem-connector-master 2/aem-connector/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/commerce/gui/content/catalogs/importblueprintswizard/importers/magento/`
  - .content.xml file under `/magento2-aem-connector-master 2/aem-connector/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/commerce/gui/content/products/importproductswizard/importers/magento/`
- Rebuild and install the package 'mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage'

Check the repository.. nodes should have installed correctly:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download and install this Package in package manager: [updated package for AEM Magento Integration](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1JcVyuYh0l-2GmIx7mulcYmPM437ud0Bp&export=download).

After that follow below steps to import catalog:

1. Goto AEM navigation screen, click on "commerce" > click on "Catalogs".
2. Create folder magento, goto magento folder.
3. click on create, then "Import Blueprints".
4. Select Magento from Importer.
5. Enter server URL(not admin URL), admin username, password, write and name  for catalog and write "we-retail" in theme.
6. Click on import.
7. Catalog will be imported.

To import products follow below steps:

1. Goto AEM navigation screen, click on "commerce" > click on "Products".
2. Create folder magento, goto magento folder.
3. click on create, then "Import Products".
4. Select Magento from Importer.
5. Enter server URL(not admin URL), admin username, and password.
6. Click on import.
7. Catalog will be imported.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the AEM connector from: https://helpx.adobe.com/it/experience-manager/6-4/sites/deploying/using/magento.html

Inside the `magento2-aem-connector-master.zip`, there are two folders

1. `aem-connector`
2. `magento2`

In AEM side, follow the steps:

- extract `aem-connector` and go to the location:

  ```
  magento2-aem-connector-master\aem-connector\ui.apps\src\main\content\jcr_root\apps\commerce\gui\content\catalogs\importblueprintswizard\importers\magento
  ```
- here, one content file available open and change the line "3":

  - from: `jcrSmiley TonguerimaryType="nt:unstructured"`
  - to: `jcrSmiley TonguerimaryType="slingSmiley Surprisedrderedfolder"` and
- extract `magento2`, and go to the location:

  ```
  magento2-aem-connector-master\aem-connector\ui.apps\src\main\content\jcr_root\apps\commerce\gui\content\products\importproductswizard\importers\magento
  ```
- open it and change:

  - from: `jcrSmiley TonguerimaryType="nt:unstructured"`
  - to:  `jcrSmiley TonguerimaryType="slingSmiley Surprisedrderedfolder"`
- Save both product and catalog file.
- Upload to the aem connector to eclipse and build the package using maven:

  ```
  mvn clean install -P installPackage
  ```
- check the package available in AEM  package manager

  ```
  http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/index.jsp
  ```
- also:

  - http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles magento bundle in active state.
  - under http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr

    - configure the Magento identity provider, synchandler, external login module:

      ```
      magento2-aem-connector-master\aem-connector\readme --follow file
      ```