# Adobe Experience Manager 6.4 - installing Magento 2 connector

Tags: integration, aem, magento2.2

Could anyone help me with installing Magento 2 connector for AEM? 
Instruction on official site is very simple - [official guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/deploying/using/magento.html).

I don't know where to start with it.
In general I'm trying to integrate (for practice) Magento 2 with AEM to look how it works, find benefits.

Comment: Yep, as you've mentioned instructions in the article seem easy peazy! All you require is an AEM instance and the packages mentioned in the article. Give it a crack and let us know if you get stuck anywhere and the community should be able to help.

Comment: I've installed AEM locally on my machine (double click *.jar) and it's running on standard location localhost:4502. I've downloaded 'magento2-aem-connector-master.zip' and copy/paste folder 'aem-connector' under 'crx-quickstart\install'. Restart of AEM and nothing happened, Magento Identity Provider isn't available.

Comment: Try installing directly using the Package Manager: http://localhost:4504/crx/packmgr/index.jsp

Look first if the connector is not in the list of the uploaded packages. In any case, Upload, check Force Upload (if it exists), then click on Install.

Comment: Ok. For now I used Maven with command `mvn clean install` on `crx-quickstart\install\aem-connector`and I can see new package on CRX. I also figured out that I need Java 8, not 10. Current problem is an error on install this package - _Error: javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: OakConstraint0025: /apps/commerce/gui/content/catalogs/importblueprintswizard/importers[[nt:folder]]: Unexpected child node magento found in a new node_.

Comment: Other thing, when I use Maven with `mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage` I get error _[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.24:install (install-package) on project magento2.content: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]_

Comment: Added a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242513/4122891

Answer (score 0):

Download and install this Package in package manager: [updated package for AEM Magento Integration](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1JcVyuYh0l-2GmIx7mulcYmPM437ud0Bp&export=download).

After that follow the steps below to import the catalog:

1. Goto AEM navigation screen, click on "commerce" > click on "Catalogs".
2. Create folder magento, goto magento folder.
3. click on create, then "Import Blueprints".
4. Select Magento from Importer.
5. Enter server URL(not admin URL), admin username, password, write and name for catalog and write "we-retail" in theme.
6. Click on import.
7. Catalog will be imported.

To import products follow below steps:

1. Goto AEM navigation screen, click on "commerce" > click on "Products".
2. Create folder magento, goto magento folder.
3. click on create, then "Import Products".
4. Select Magento from Importer.
5. Enter server URL(not admin URL), admin username, and password.
6. Click on import.
7. Catalog will be imported.